# Binding a list with deviders to the DOM AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to group a list of people that are located in an array, first by their street and then by number and then bind them to the DOM using **ng-repeat**. The result I want is this:

```
{
   'street1':{
      '1':[ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ] ,
      '2':[ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ]
   },
   'street2':{
      '1':[ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ] ,
      '2':[ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ]
   }
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
    var tmp = {};
    for (i = 0; i < Names.length; i++) {
        var street = Names[i].Street;
        var num = Names[i].Number;
        var name = Names[i].Name;
        if (tmp[street] == undefined) {
            tmp[street] = {};

        }
        var str = tmp[street];
        if (str[num] == undefined) {
            str[num] = [];
        }
        str[num].push(name);
    }
    var $scope.filteredTerrInfo = tmp;
```

**HTML:**

```
     <ion-list data-ng-repeat="(street, numbers) in filteredTerrInfo">

        <div class="item item-divider">
            <h2> {{street}}</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-divider" data-ng-repeat="(number, names) in numbers">
            <h2>{{number}}</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-left-thumbnail" data-ng-repeat="x in names">
            <h2>{{x}}</h2>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
```

The code above displays the street and number deviders but can't display the names list. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `names` value is not accessible since `data-ng-repeat="x in names"` is outside `data-ng-repeat="(number, names) in numbers"` loop. Try changing template to:

```
<div class="item item-divider" data-ng-repeat="(number, names) in numbers">
   <h2>{{number}}</h2>
   <div class="item item-left-thumbnail" data-ng-repeat="x in names">
      <h2>{{x}}</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```